# Trying to reduce memory usage of script

Tags: php, memory

I am a math teacher who has built an online testing site for my school to use (aka, not a pro). The site has worked well but as the amount of usage at my school increases I am starting to run into memory problems (I think). After I have about 50 to 60 users simultaneously using the site the whole website begins to crash, it will come back up after a few minutes. I never have this problem with low usage. The page where students take their quiz loads 10 questions on the page, each multiple choice with 4 radio options. (Not a lot of jquery going on). Each time the user clicks an answer I am using ajax to store their answer in the database. Below is the jquery code that sends their clicks as they take the quiz.

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
var questionId = $(this).parent().parent().find('.qid').val();
var answer = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertqanswerajax.php",
        data: {questionId: questionId, answer: answer},
    });

});
```

When I load system process in my cpanel I see there are 5 different processes running, each around 80 megabytes. The maximum in my php.ini is set to 540MB. If I check the page with memory_get_peak_usage() it never reads above about half a megabyte, however in the console timeline I can see the memory usage is almost up to 10 megabytes for one user (images below). What do I need to check, or what is the best way to troubleshoot the discrepancy? What could be causing the problems? I can provide more information if needed, I am just not sure what all is relevant.

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Here is the code for the php file accessed via ajax

```
<?php session_start();
include('../includes/startup.php');
$questionId = $_POST['questionId'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];



insertQuizAnswer($questionId, $userId, $answer, 1);


?>
```

The function called in that file:

```
function insertQuizAnswer($questionId, $userId, $answer, $testId){
global $DB;                                          
$standardsHandle = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO quizanswers (questionid, userid,answer,testid)    
VALUES (:questionId,:userId, :answer, :testId)
                                ");   
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':questionId', $questionId);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':answer', $answer);
$standardsHandle->bindParam(':testId', $testId);
$standardsHandle->execute();    
}
```

And the startup file loaded on both:

```
<?php
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [2-7]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
// if IE < 8
echo "My Class Progress does not Work with this version of Internet Explorer</br>
<a href='https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/'>Click Here to Download a more modern browser</a>";
exit;
}
else
{

}
if(isset($_POST['getGrade'])){
$_SESSION['gradeLevel'] = $_POST['getGrade'];
}
if(isset($_POST['getSubject'])){
$_SESSION['subject'] = $_POST['getSubject'];
}
include_once('../functions/userfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/goalfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/modulefunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/globalfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/skillfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/quizfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/practicefunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/benchmarkfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/dockfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/dashboardfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../functions/notificationfunctions.php');   //all functions
include_once('../includes/connect.php');     //connect to database
$userSubject = $_SESSION['subject'];
$userGradeLevel = $_SESSION['gradeLevel'];
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 'true'){
}   
    else{
    header('location: ../../index.php');
    die();
    }
```

?>

Here is the connect.php file that is accessed:

```
try {                                                                                 
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);   
}

catch(PDOException $e) {      
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up server's memory and client's memory, what do you actually mean under "website begins to crash"?

Comment: Once I hit anywhere from 40 to 50 users on this page taking a quiz, the website goes down, if you try to visit any page the browsers just brings up a general error saying page not found. It then comes back up after a few minutes. No errors in the error logs.

Comment: ok, do I understand right: your server is outside your university network and when 50-60 students trying to open the same page on this server - you see message "404 file not found", looks like either university network routers cut requests or server-side DDoS prevention system

Comment: I have been trying to figure out if it is a memory issue or a DDoS issue, I thought it my be GoDaddy preventing requests, wouldn't that make more sense? My site is not on my school's network. How could I determine if that is the issue?

Comment: yes, it can be, one of possible quick checks - open really not existing page on your site, is it actually the same page which you see when students trying to open it? or you can [modify your 404 page](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1/setting-up-a-custom-404-page) to see the difference (or maybe there will no difference)

Comment: No, I have a default 404 page when the server can not find a file. The error I get from the browser is a browser generated error message, like it can not connect to the server.

Comment: I see, so it is 90% on network level, btw lets do another check on scripts itself - do you handle all errors (like database connections, invalid queries) in scripts? Sometimes there can be situations when some error occurred in php script and the result is 500 error on client (usually displayed as "cannot connect")

Comment: to check php errors I suggest you to enable error output in php.ini, turn off default error page in browsers, add `error_reporting(0xffff);` to code, and use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to set your own error handlers

Comment: No, I am a bit of a novice, I do not have a great system for error handling. I have never run into any errors over the past year until now that the volume has started to rear up, some days there are 1 or 2 hundreds simultaneous users.

Comment: ok, I suppose it is only 2 simple scripts, maybe post it - at least we will check what can be wrong at this part, and then try to understand what can be on network level

Comment: put the app on a another server and simulate load with something like [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: I added the files that the ajax script calls

Comment: not so simply as I thought :) so, try to use custom error handlers as I wrote before - just make `echo 'error';die();` in them to find out whether your scripts actually called during "high-load" times

Comment: I certainly will, I do not think the script is being accessed. It does not matter what page you try and visit, once the site is down... it is down. Even if I try to access the site via mobile, aka, not the school's network, the site will not load.

Comment: Do you really need all of those files and functions to be loaded and used at the same time? Also, are you perhaps always using a new db connection instead of reusing the old one? Or are you perhaps allowing it to never be disconnected?

Comment: then I suppose the only possible solution is to ask godaddy, their support will be able to help better

Comment: I am always using a new database connection, I was under the impression that when using a PDO object to access MySql I needed to establish a new connection inside of each function. Should I be assigning null to standardsHandle or to DB?

Comment: I added the connect.php file so you can see where the $DB is set.

Answer (score 0):

The amount memory used is dependent on ini_set('memory_limit'); This amoutn is reserved by Apache, it doesn't matter how much the script actually uses until it runs out of memory.

Comment: That's a statement rather than an answer, it should have been a comment